# Why is the derivative of $y = f(x^3)$ equal to $f'(x^3) * 3x^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Why is the derivative of this function:
$ y = f(x^3)$
equal to
$y'= f'(x^3)* 3x^2$

instead of just:
$y' = f'(x^3)$

I know it has something to do with one of the rules (chain?) but I am not sure how it would apply in this situation.

Comment: It is precisely the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) $(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)\cdot g'$ and in this case works like that because the derivative of $x^3$ is $3x^2$

Comment: Try a specific counterexample. What if $f(x) = x^2$? Then $y = f(x^3) = (x^3)^2 = x^6$. Compute $y'$ and $f'(x^3)$, and compare them.

Comment: Re Henry's comment, if $g(x) = x^3$ then $f(x^3) = (f \circ g)(x).$

Comment: @Henry I think I somewhat understand, but in the chain rule you multiply the coefficient with the exponent. I am not sure how that applies to this example.

Comment: It is *entirely* due to the chain rule.  A derivative is the rate of change of a function *relative to the rate of change* of a variable.  The $f'(x^3)$ would be the rate of change of $f(x^3)$ relative to the rate of change of $x^3$ but the rate of change of $f(x^3)$ relative to the rate of change of $x$ we need to take the rate of change of $x^3$ relative to $x$ as well.  Read up on the chain rule and understand how and *why* it works that that will make this utterly clear.

Comment: " I think I somewhat understand, but in the chain rule you multiply the coefficient with the exponent. I am not sure how that applies to this example"  Nothing to do with coefficients and exponents and it applies to *any* type of function.  The rule is: $[f(g(x))]' = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$.  If $f(x^3)$ then $g(x) = x^3$ and $g'(x) = 3x^2$. And so $[f(x^3)]'=[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x) = f'(x^3)\cdot (3x^2)$.  Go back and *study* the chain rule.There is really nothing more than can be said.  The chain rule IMO is the *most* important rule there is.

Comment: @fleablood Do you memorize the rule by its formula?

Comment: It doesn't *just* apply to polynomials.  If $f(x) = \frac 1{\sin x}$ then if $g(x) = \sin x$ and $h(y)=\frac 1y$ then $f(x) = h\circ g(x)$ and $f'(x) = h'(g(x))\cdot g'(x) = -\frac 1{[g(x)]^2}\cdot g'(x)=-\frac 1{\sin^2 x}\cdot \sin'x = -\frac 1{\sin^2 x}\cos x$. And likewise if $f(x) = \sin \frac 1x$ then $f'(x) = \cos \frac 1x\cdot (-\frac 1{x^2}) = -\frac {\cos \frac 1x}{x^2}$.

Comment: "Do you memorize the rule by its formula?"  Uh, yes... As I said it's the *absolute* most important derivative rule there is so I must absolutely do have it memorized so that if secret agents abduct me in my sleep I'll be able to recite it while in a drug induced coma.  And I make sure I can derive it at a moment notice.

Comment: Actually, in Leibniz notation it's a particularly *beautiful* and intuitive formula.  $\frac {d f(g(x))}{dx} = \frac {df(g(x))}{dg(x)}\frac {dg(x)}{dx}$.  Which is exactly as view derivatives of limits of fractions would imply they ought to act.

Comment: Study this!  This isn't something you'll be able to get by with "somewhat understanding".

Comment: @fleablood Any video recommendations?

Comment: "Any video recommendations?"  No.  Any textbook and any class and talking to your professor will all do as well as any other.

Comment: Video possibilities include [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/dc-chain) and [3brown1blue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YG15m2VwSjA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a particular rule that we call the chain rule. It can be derived as follows: let $f(g(x))$ be a composition of two differentiable functions. Then, $$ f(g(x))' = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(g(x))-f(g(x_0))}{x-x_0},\quad x=x_0 $$ Which is precisely $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac {f(g(x))-f(g(x_0))}{g(x)-g(x_0)}\cdot\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ since $$\lim_{y\to y_0} \frac {f(y)-f(y_0)}{y-y_0} =  f'(y_0)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac {g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}= g'(x_0)$$ we have, setting $g(x)=y,\quad g(x_0)=y_0$ $$ f(g(x_0))' = f'(g(x_0)) g'(x_0)$$ which is precisley the chain rule. Plugging in $g(x)=x^3$, we get $$f(g(x_0))'=f'(x_0^3)\cdot 3x_0^2$$ which is just the derivative of $f(x^3)$ at $x=x_0$.